# find many word that match in a pattern file (txt file)

Tags: unix

### Unix system fine all word in a txt file, key word in a pattern file

EX: pattern file txt
1
2
3

EX: a.txt file we want to fine out that word contain 1 or 2 or 3
a
2
4
3
5
4
1
2

Result like:
2
3
1
2

---

I had try awk, but not good 
awk '/1/,/2/,/3/,....  a.txt

Comment: `grep -Ff pattern.txt a.txt`

Comment: look like work, but some weirdly when a.txt modify like this : 2a ,  3a , 1a, 2a, Resutl will only show 3a

Comment: replace `F` by `E`. have a look at `man grep`

Comment: not work, some key word will lost,  i try grep -w '1\|2\|3\|'  will be right Result, but not my request

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an exact match between `pattern.txt` and `a.txt`. This implies if `pattern.txt` contains a line:

```
foo
```

then this line can only match "foo" and not

```
bar foo
foo bar
foo123
```

For a perfect match you can do:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){a[$0];next}($0 in a)' pattern.txt a.txt
$ grep -xFf pattern.txt a.txt
```